# In which short story escape-pod occupant stays inside to die while the outside was transformed?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A small ship or escape pod has landed on a planet with one living survivor. I think it is the regular waste dumps that - over the period of a year or so - alter the local ecology outside, somehow making the environment more suitable so that the character could have lived longer, had they known. I think there is some kind of threshold effect - once the change in the local chemistry started, it continued on its own. Written in the 80's or 90's?

Comment: another question about unanticipated environmental change [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/123322/51174)

Comment: Yep @JoeL. - that's it! How do I proceed - should I delete this question?

Comment: @uhol: I've flagged it as a duplicate. The moderators should take it from here.